# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils

Tags: java, opencsv

Here is the code

```
public static void readCSV() {
    String inputFile = "memberInfo1.csv";
    try {

        // Create an object of filereader
        // class with CSV file as a parameter.
        FileReader filereader = new FileReader(inputFile);

        // create csvReader object passing
        // file reader as a parameter
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(filereader);
        String[] nextRecord;

        // we are going to read data line by line
        while ((nextRecord = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            for (String cell : nextRecord) {
                System.out.print(cell + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        csvReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error that I am receiving is pictured
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgk5T.png)
I already added the opencsv-5.5.2. jar to the classpath pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kef3L.png)
I am running Java 11.0.12 installed through homebrew.
Is there another step that I am missing?

Comment: Please include you pom or gradle as this probably is a dependency issue.

Comment: You need it on your runtime classpath as well.

Comment: the error message was indicated that `org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils` can not be found. So you need add the apache commons-lang3  jar to the class path.

Comment: Adding the apache-commons-lang3 jar to the classpath solved my problem, thank you

Comment: Consider adding the solution as an answer and accept it so that the question can be "closed" and others might benefit from it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Brandon. I am joyful of my comment that can solve this problem. I'll write the answer that you can accept and close this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message was indicated that org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils can not be found. So you need add the apache commons-lang3 jar to the class path.